# Python optimisation

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, solver

I have data from two points that I have measured and I have data from two points that I have calculated. I'm trying to minimise the difference between these data. e.g.

Minimise difference between Point 1 (measured) and Point 1 (calculated).
Minimise difference between Point 2 (measured) and Point 2 (calculated).

The values of Point 1 (calculated) and Point 2 (calculated) are connected  as part of a quadratic distribution: a*x^2+b*x+c.  I wish to change the 'a' parameter only.

Therefore I am trying to minimise the difference for Point 1 and Point 2 by changing only one parameter.

How would I do this using python? I'm thinking of using scipy, what would be a suitable optimiser?

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.optimize` has some good methods such as `fsolve`, `root`, and `minimize`. Read the documentation to figure out how they work, but here's a short example to find the root of a linear function:

```
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def function_to_find_root_of(x, slope, yintercept):
    ''' x is a list of all the variables you need to minimize
        the other variables will be passed in as constants '''

    return slope*x + yintercept

m = 4
b = 7
print fsolve(function_to_find_root_of, x0=[10], args=(m, b), xtol=1e-10)
#prints [-1.75], which is the root of y=4x+7
```